# Pandas Dataframe reads value of one column wrong

Tags: python, pandas

The csv file:
[Link to Github](https://github.com/liamrisch/helper/blob/master/log_1_2018_09_07.csv)

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("log_1_2018_09_07.csv", encoding="ISO-8859-1", delimiter=';')
print(df.columns.tolist())
dates = []
times = []
outputs = []

for date in df.loc[:, "Datum"]:
    dates.append(date)
    print("date")
    print(date)
for time in df.loc[:, " Zeit"]:
    times.append(time)
    print("time")
    print(time)
for out in df.iloc[:, 19]:
    print("output")
    outputs.append(out)
    print(out)
```

It reads the dates and times correctly, but the 19th column (column T) are all 0 and the 6th value is 990, however pandas reads it as all 0 and the 9th value as 1.
Does anybody know why it's reading the wrong values?
Thank you!!

Comment: Hi, the data on github is corrupted. Can you give us the valid one?

Comment: Pandas is right. I checked your data and indeed the 6th value in column 19 is 0 and the 9th value in column 19 is 1. (You have to start with 0 when counting the columns.)

Comment: Thanks, my problem was that I was using LibreOffice Calc to view the data which actually showed wrong values, so the pandas values were right afterall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://raw.github.com/liamrisch/helper/master/log_1_2018_09_07.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, encoding="ISO-8859-1", delimiter=';')

df.iloc[:,[6,19]]
```

**Gives:**

```
Teil 1-8 - Abstand Rasthaken MP1-MP2    Teil 1-8
0   26,764  0
1   26,787  0
2   26,792  0
3   26,788  0
4   26,771  0
5   999,990 0
6   26,786  0
7   26,785  0
8   26,780  1
9   26,783  0
10  26,798  0
```

Answer (score 0):

take a very close look at the data, the value is actually `1` but since `999` takes more visual space it makes the illusion of 999 being the value in that cell.

printing the `df` in that column (before any maniulation) shows the actual values of that column, without any surprises.